# include js script from a npm install

Tags: javascript, npm

I have a server where I cannot run npm, lack of permissions. Just Apache.

I need a JS library (ie: https://github.com/stevage/mapbox-gl-utils) that is deployed using npm. There is no 'old-style' JS script in which there is all I need (and that I can reference to in my html)

I used npm localy (own laptop, where I have permissions) and now I have a bunch of inter-dependent folders, with JS and json files, that as far as I know, only work into a npm server instance.

No JS including all necessary stuff has been created.

What do I have to do to make work the JS I need into my standard html (served on Apache)? or I am forced to use npm?

Comment: Just a comment that I (the maintainer of mapbox-gl-utils) have now included a UMD build (with Rollup, similar to the answer from Olian04), so you can access that "old-style" JS script here: https://unpkg.com/mapbox-gl-utils

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pull down the npm dependency on a different computer, bundle it as a single JS file using any bundler of choice (for example [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/)). Then move that bundled file to the server and use it as you would with any JS file you've written your self.

First install dependencies:

```sh
$ npm i mapbox-gl-utils rollup rollup-plugin-node-resolve rollup-plugin-commonjs
```

Then setup rollup:

```js
// rollup.config.js
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';

export default {
  input: './node_modules/mapbox-gl-utils/src/index.js',
  output: {
    file: './mapbox-gl-utils.js',
    format: 'iife',
    name: 'mapbox_gl_utils'
  },
  plugins: [
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
  ]
}
```

Finally run rollup to bundle your dependency:

```sh
$ rollup --config
```

Comment: thanks! just for reference, I had to add  json() in plugins.
So this new JS is free of nodeJS dependencies, is plain JS? Because I am trying to do basic stuff like the API says... but I see that require() is a nodeJS function and no idea how to translate this to JS..
https://github.com/stevage/mapbox-gl-utils

// Adds U property to map, containing these methods.
const U = require('mapbox-gl-utils').init(map);
// Certain methods (eg hoverPopup) require access to the mapboxgl library itself
const mapboxgl = require('mapbox-gl');
const U = require('mapbox-gl-utils').init(map, mapboxgl);